# Using Font Awesome, how to get rid of underline on hover?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I am using the a:after method for a dynamic cookie trail menu:

topic  >  topic  >  topic  >  topic

where the ">" is an icon from font awesome

But I want to get rid of the underline from the ">" when hovering over the topics

Here's my code:

```
<div id="cookie">

 <ul>
<li><a href='#'>Leaders</a> </li>
<li><a href='#'>Topic</a> </li>
<li>Topic</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried various methods of a:hover on the after css but no luck.

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DhgM/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were doing `:after` on the entire link, `a`, not the `li`. Do the following instead.

```
#cookie ul li:after { //changed this line
content: '\f105';
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0px 0px 0px 12px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9k5sf/) is a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:after` on the `li` instead.

```
#cookie ul li:after {
    content: '\f105';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the `li` element

You will need to remove the font awesome from the last child for consistency

```
#cookie ul li:after {
     content: '\f105';
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     text-decoration:none;
     padding:0px 0px 0px 12px;
}
#cookie ul li:last-child:after {
    content: '';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/9k5sf/1/

Answer (score -1):

I've been wrestling with an underline when using font-awesome in Wordpress. My solution was to set border:0; Turns out the "line" was a border, not a text-decoration.

Comment: My bad. Should have paid closer attention to the question.